Screen is not edge to edge

I updated target sdk to 35 and called the enableEdgeToEdge() but it is still not edge-to-edge for some reason. The application I am working on is a combination of fragment and jetpack compose
so I did everything from enabling edge-to-edge documentation

If you are using Scaffold in you composable then you also have to set the following:
Scaffold(
    contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp), 
    ...
) 

If you are not using Scaffold then please share your composable.

Perfectly worked, thanks a lot

@Pragno, can you give me reference of this solution, I think I didn't see them in documentation about edge to edge

They have not given a example specifically for Scaffold. I knew the answer because I also had the problem before. But his might help: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/layouts/insets#override-default
